# Problems about using C++ coroutines

Tags: c++, asynchronous, coroutine

I'm experimenting the incoming C++ coroutines with [liburing](https://github.com/axboe/liburing).

I'm a JavaScript developer and trying to implement a function like [Promise.all](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/all)

My first attempt

```cpp
template <typename T>
task<std::vector<T>> taskAll1(std::vector<task<T>> list) {
    std::vector<T> result;
    result.reserve(list.size());
    for (auto&& t : list) {
        result.push_back(co_await t);
    }
    co_return result;
}
```

[task](https://github.com/CarterLi/liburing-http-demo/blob/12af992d0d87a721bbe67bb67aee8e4b0e965114/task.hpp#L11) is modified from [gor_task](https://github.com/Quuxplusone/coro/blob/master/include/coro/gor_task.h). I mainly make [`task::promise_type::initial_suspend` return `suspend_never`](https://github.com/CarterLi/liburing-http-demo/blob/async/task.hpp#L17) to let coroutines start by default.

The usage:

```cpp
// async_delay: https://github.com/CarterLi/liburing-http-demo/blob/12af992d0d87a721bbe67bb67aee8e4b0e965114/async_coro.hpp#L68
// It waits some seconds asynchronously and then prints the number of seconds it waits.
task<bool> start() {
    // TODO: less verbose code?
    std::vector<task<int>> vec;
    vec.emplace_back(async_delay(1));
    vec.emplace_back(async_delay(2));
    vec.emplace_back(async_delay(3));
    co_await taskAll<int>(std::move(vec));
    co_return true;
}
```

The code works as expected. But if I rearrange the order of `emplace_back`s, for example let `async_delay(2)` come before `async_delay(1)`, the code still runs but freezes at the end of program. I know it is because the task `async_delay(1)` is resolved before it's awaited, but I have no idea how to fix it.

The second attempt, what I want to to do is translating following JS code into C++

```js
/** @param {Promise<any>[]} list */
function taskAll(list) {
  return new Promise(resolve => {
    const result = new Array(list.length);
    let left = list.length;
    list.forEach((p, i) => {
      p.then(x => {
        result[i] = x;
        left--;
        if (!left) resolve(result);
      })
    });
  });
}
```

The c++ code

```cpp
// completion: https://github.com/CarterLi/liburing-http-demo/blob/12af992d0d87a721bbe67bb67aee8e4b0e965114/task.hpp#L78
// It's like JS Promise and can be awaited directly without calling an async function
template <typename T>
task<std::vector<T>> taskAll(std::vector<task<T>> list) {
    std::vector<T> result(list.size());
    size_t left = list.size();
    completion<std::vector<T>> promise;
    for (size_t i=0; i<list.size(); ++i) {
        [&, i]() mutable -> task<bool> {
            result[i] = co_await list[i];
            left--;
            if (!left) promise.resolve(std::move(result));
            co_return true;
        }();
    }
    co_await promise;
    co_return result;
}
```

The code crashes immediately. Async code is really hard to debug and I gave up.

Full code [can be found in Github](https://github.com/CarterLi/liburing-http-demo/tree/async), please help.

Answer (score 0):

For 2nd attempt, I found that I forgot to assign the task returned by lambda expression, which make the task destruct immediately after the lambda function returned.